# C/C++ RPC Tutorial for Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, rpc

Can someone point me to a decent RPC tutorial for (or books) linux, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585012/c-rpc-tutorial) post.  I tried looking around myself, I've only found tutorials that are really old.

Thanks

Comment: The term RPC is generic. Do you have a specific protocol in mind like Sun RPC? The tutorials are old because the protocol *is* really old. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call

Comment: You found old tutorials because RPC goes way back.  It's been reinvented half a dozen times over the years.  What's your motivation?

Comment: Half a dozen is probably off by an order of magnitude or 3 :-)

If you've got the general idea of what it is you can roll your own and reinvent it again pretty easily.

Comment: I was thinking of major implementations that got some market penetration.  To create anything that would even get glanced at by people today would definitely not be trivial.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the idea of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) goes back to 1976 and the first business use was by Xerox in 1981, I'm not exactly sure what qualifies as a really old tutorial.

Here are a few resources you might find helpful.

- [Power Programming with RPC](http://books.google.com/books?id=PN2hcRD29JUC&dq=Power+Programming+with+RPC) (1992)
- [Remote Procedure Calls | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2204) (Oct 01, 1997)
- [Remote Procedure Calls (RPC)](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html) (1999)
- [Remote Procedure Call Programming Guide](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/23.rpc/paper.pdf) (PDF link)
- [rpc(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rpc)

Comment: That Linux Journal one was the old one I was talking  about.  I suppose RPC is a more mature technology than I thought.  Also the third one on your list:  I can't build the first example.  There's no definition of rnusers() in the included libraries.

Comment: The `rnusers()` function returns the number of users logged on to the specified host via `rpc.rusersd`.  I have been unable to find an equivalent function in Linux.  Here's a link to the `rpc.rusersd` manpage - http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpc.rusersd