# Undefined reference to svc_create

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, rpc

My problem is the following: I'm trying to implement a C RPC example and I keep running into the following compiler error:

```
remote_exec.c: In function ‘main’:
remote_exec.c:13:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘svc_create’
remote_exec.o: In function `main':
remote_exec.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `svc_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "rls.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{       
   extern void execute();

   const char* nettype = "tcp";
   int no_of_handles;

   no_of_handles = svc_create(execute, EXECPROG, EXECVERS, nettype);

   svc_run();
   return 0;
}
```

I really don't know how to solve this. The man page and all the examples I've studied just say to include rpc/rpc.h, however it doesn't seem to work. I am compiling with

```
gcc -Wall -c
```

Comment: What's your OS, and what OS were the examples you're following intended for?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.04. The examples were targeting linux.

Comment: Strange, I don't think that API exists on Linux (it's Sun RPC I think). Link to that example?

Comment: If you go here: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html it is listed in the "Top level routines" section.

Comment: That doesn't reference Linux. It's "UNIX" in general, but in that case it uses Sun's RPC library which is not (as far as I know/can find) portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function as `svc_create` on linux in libc. See the manpage for rpc. Your guide is using the transport independent(ti) RPC library of Solaris and other unixes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526227/c-c-rpc-tutorial-for-linux) question for RPC guides for linux.

The RPC library in linux is based on a slightly different RPC library than the ti-RPC library from Sun, though there is a ti-RPC library here: http://nfsv4.bullopensource.org/doc/tirpc_rpcbind.php , if you use that library, you link with `-ltirpc`

You probably need `svctcp_create` or `svcudp_create` if you're using the standard RPC library included in glibc.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I wasn't using the correct function. :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to link against the library when you create your program. If the library is called `rpc`, for example, this would be done by adding `-lrpc` to the compiler command line that creates the final executable.