# C library to implement RPC

Tags: c, rpc

I could not find any libraries that C provides to use RPC. I need to use RPC in C. Is there a way if there is no library support? I am looking for a non-blocking implementation.

Comment: There are many variants of RPC, from the old Sun variant (now [ONC-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONC_RPC)), to modern variants such as [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml-rpc).

Comment: Your question is vague; there is a lot out there on RPC:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526227/c-c-rpc-tutorial-for-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526227/c-c-rpc-tutorial-for-linux), or a simple Google search:[http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=rpc+in+c](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=rpc+in+c).  Could you be more specific in what you are looking for?

Comment: can you make your question more specific?

Comment: Can some one point me to  a link where we have a example of a non-blocking RPC supported on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

i made good progress with XML-RPC (http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

A very nice implementation of RPC using the rpcgen; presumeably the best C library for RPC implementation is provided by [tuitorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/rpcgen.htm).

Check it out.